# Is there any way to hide the components of the app component in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, frontend, toolbar

I'm working on a chat software UI. I has coded the Tool Bar in the **app.component.html**.
Then I coded the Login and Register button in the separate components and route them. Initially my home page looks like this.[Please click on the link to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8htL.jpg)

When I click on Login or Register it will look like this. [Please click on the link to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSIzf.jpg)

After log in also the Tool bar still contains the Login and Register button how can I hide those ? Below is my **app.component.html**

```
`<mat-toolbar class = "tb">
  <span class = "tit">My App</span>
  <span class="example-spacer"></span>
  <button mat-stroked-button class="lb" routerLink = "log">Login</button>
  <button mat-stroked-button class="rb" routerLink = "reg">Register</button>
</mat-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
```

Below is my **app.component.ts** code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'demo';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple set an [hidden]="!show" in the elements (login/register links).

something like :
`login(){ userService.loggedIn = true; this.show = false; }`

Comment: Could you please tell me more descriptively ? In which file I need to paste the above code. I'm Newbie

Comment: you have a component for navbar where the login/register are created. if you have somethin like `<a href="#" [hidden]="!show">login</a>`. then the navbar component should have the this.show and set it there

Comment: following the official tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4, `Services are a great way to share information among classes that don't know each other. `